# Facing Issue in Linked server connection

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

We connected the linked server in SQL and getting the connection issue when running a test connection. The same server connected in another SQL and it works. There is no restriction in the firewall.

Error Message:
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "server ip" returned message "Client unable to establish connection". Msg 10054, Level 16, State 1, Line 11 TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

1st  one is when testing the connection

[image: Image 1]

2nd one is while executing the query.

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to Stack Overflow! I know it's a bit tedious, but can you be sure to copy and paste the messages into your original post, instead of just including screenshots? That might be a bit easier to read, and will also help other people with similar errors find this thread in the future.

Comment: This is the error message.



 OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "45.76.15.212,4858" returned message "Client unable to establish connection".
Msg 10054, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.